# Bash Replace String in a variable using regex

Tags: regex, bash

I am trying to replace a string in a variable using regex. However as soon as I use regex it's not working.

**Source String:**

The number could be anything, any valid integer.

```
message='"autotermination_minutes": 15,'
```

**Expected String**

```
   message='"autotermination_minutes": 30,'
```

Following is working (without regex)

```
echo ${message/'"autotermination_minutes": 15'/'"autotermination_minutes": 30'}
```

**Following doesn't work (with Regex)**

```
echo ${message/'"autotermination_minutes": '[0-9]/'"autotermination_minutes": 30'}
```

it shows, following output

```
"autotermination_minutes": 305,
```

Comment: Is your actual input a JSON object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[0-9]` only matches a single digit.

Use `[0-9][0-9]` to match two:

```
➜ echo ${message/'"autotermination_minutes": '[0-9][0-9]/'"autotermination_minutes": 30'}
"autotermination_minutes": 30,
```

Note that Bash parameter substitutions are very limited in functionality. What you're doing here doesn't even have anything to do with regular expressions—these  patterns are just globs. So, instead of a `[0-9]+` that you'd expect from a regex, you need to use `+([0-9])` to match one or more digits:

```
➜ shopt -s extglob
➜ echo ${message/'"autotermination_minutes": '+([0-9])/'"autotermination_minutes": 30'}
"autotermination_minutes": 15,
```

See also [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88480/bash-var-search-replace-and-weird-regex-behaviour).

But you really should be using `sed` or `perl`:

```
➜ echo "$message" | sed -E 's/[0-9]+/30/'
"autotermination_minutes": 30,
```

Or, if your input is JSON, you *really* should be using a JSON parser and read/write the file properly rather than using regular expressions.

Comment: number could be any valid integer not only two digits. it could be `120` or `240` as well

Comment: Your question did not specify that. See updated answer for a Bash-only solution. But really, use `sed` or `perl` with proper regular expressions.

Comment: I don't have to just change digits, I have a very long string. I have just pasted part of that as example. I would need following as well as part of pattern `"autotermination_minutes":`

Comment: following is not working `echo $message | sed 's/"autotermination_minutes": [0-9]+/"autotermination_minutes": 30'/`

Comment: @GaurangShah You're missing the `-E` for `sed`, without which `+` has to be escaped.

Comment: @GaurangShah You also should double-quote variable references (e.g. `echo "$message"` instead of just `echo $message`) -- without them, weird things can happen if the string contains spaces and/or anything that looks like a filename wildcard. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting common mistakes like this.

Answer (score 1):

In pure bash, there is no way to capture a value from original string and have it back in replacement using a back-reference.

You may use a simple `sed` here with a capture group and back-reference:

```
message='"autotermination_minutes": 15,'
sed -E 's/("autotermination_minutes": *)[0-9]+/\130/' <<< "$message"
```

```
"autotermination_minutes": 30,
```

Comment: `echo ${message} |   sed 's/"autotermination_minutes": [0-9]*/"autotermination_minutes": 90'/`` worked for me. is there any issue with this. `[0-9=+` is not working though

Comment: @GaurangShah You need `sed -E` to enable "extended" regular expression syntax, such as "`+`".

Answer (score 1):

How about a bash-only solution:

```
message='"autotermination_minutes": 15,'
pattern='(.*autotermination_minutes":[[:blank:]]*)([[:digit:]]+)(.*)'
replacement='30'

if [[ $message =~ $pattern ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${replacement}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
else
    echo "$message"
fi
```

Note that it is less efficient in both code size and execution time than properly designed `sed` or `awk` solution.